# aggregate test results from different parts of the stack to one graph

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, rspec, integration-testing

These days web app are comprised of many different stacks. We have backend Ruby/Python/PHP/JavaScript/C code and then we have MVC / client-code with frameworks such as AngularJS, EmberJS etc. Essentially, developers write test code to cover their respective parts of the stack. perhaps some RSPec for the Rails stack, QUnit for JavaScript tests, Selenium for headless browser testing, etc.

My question is the following: Is there currently a framework that unites all of the results from these tests and aggregates them into one results spreadsheet/graph? I'm mostly interested in seeing the overall health of an application in one location and not going to each part of the stack and investigating them individually. How is that done these days? Are there modern tools built that are able to take the results of say rspec tests, qunit tests, selenium tests and put the results into one say, pretty graph?

Ideally I'd love to build a test framework that would have one 'GO' button for all the different stacks I work with and deliver the results to one unified output that I can display as HTML, CSV or whatever format is required at the time.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a Continuous Integration system.

Comment: Have you tried GruntJS? At least you would run all the test at the same time and maybe set up a common output for the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been and being part of complex projects which have multiple services written in java, ruby, R, scala, with different db's, and front end written in javascript framworks, native mobile apps and rails. We have something called "build monitor" something like following, showing status of different test suites, hence the state of the system in a single place, which is highly evident.
[image]
This is achieved through build tools like [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), [go](http://www.go.cd/),[team city](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity), [travis](https://travis-ci.org/). These tools provide following features.

1. Execute and consolidate results for test written in java, ruby,
   javascript, .net, R etc.. This could be unit test, integration test, functional ui tests, performance test, end-to-end test.
2. Trigger tests periodically or on code change
3. Deploy application on successful test
4. Report test results through email, sms, etc.
5. Notify which code change caused failure
6. Archive test results and show trend of test execution
7. and lot other things ...

Some theory around [Continuous Integration (CI)](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html)

Would suggest to google for more details on specif implementation on of the CI tools and specific implementation for any language and test suite.